# Php Laravel when updating data new record added instead

Tags: php, laravel

Hi i have issue when i'm trying update data in my table instead i add new record.
My update method is:

```
 public function update(CompanyUpdateRequest $request, Company $company)
    {
        try{
            $request['id'] = 1;
            $this->companyService->setModel($company)->update($request->all());
            $request->session()->flash('success', 'Nastavenie bolo zmenené!');
            return redirect('admin/company');
        }
        catch(\Exception $e){
            $request->session()->flash('warning', 'Nastavenie sa nepodarilo uložiť!' . $e);
            return redirect('admin/company');
        }
    }
```

My service update:

```
    public function update(array $data, $modelOrId = null): BaseModelService
    {
        if ($modelOrId !== null) {
            if ($modelOrId instanceof Model) {
                $this->setModel($modelOrId);
            } elseif (is_int($modelOrId)) {
                $modelOrId = $this->getRepository()->find($modelOrId);
                $this->setModel($modelOrId);
            }
        }
        $this->getModel()->fill($data)->save();
        //Here is the problem when i try to save
        return $this;
    }
```

In table there will be always one Company so I need to always update record with id 1. But when I try update as i show you on picture above with id=1 i will get message duplicate primary key. Where should be problem please?

```
App\Company {#306 ▼
  #table: "company"
  #fillable: array:13 [▼
    0 => "phone_number"
    1 => "name"
    2 => "email"
    3 => "instagram"
    4 => "facebook"
    5 => "youtube"
    6 => "gps"
    7 => "address"
    8 => "psc"
    9 => "city"
    10 => "house_number"
    11 => "name_executive_manager"
    12 => "surname_executive_manager"
  ]
  #connection: null
  #primaryKey: "id"
  #keyType: "int"
  +incrementing: true
  #with: []
  #withCount: []
  #perPage: 15
  +exists: false
  +wasRecentlyCreated: false
  #attributes: []
  #original: []
  #changes: []
  #casts: []
  #dates: []
  #dateFormat: null
  #appends: []
  #dispatchesEvents: []
  #observables: []
  #relations: []
  #touches: []
  +timestamps: true
  #hidden: []
  #visible: []
  #guarded: array:1 [▼
    0 => "*"
  ]
}
```

My update route:

```
Route::put('/admin/company/{id}', 'Admin\CompanyController@update')->name('admin_company_update');
```

Comment: try this $request['id'] = $company->id ? $company->id : 1 ;

Comment: No that's not help. Still making new record after that. But thx

Comment: show me the dd($company);

Comment: I edited question

Comment: When i add id to fillable this is output `PDOException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY' in`

Comment: I got your problem, show me your update route. no need to fillable id

Comment: Added route to last edit

Comment: got it, your function is like public function update(CompanyUpdateRequest $request, $id)
    {   $company = Company::find($id); }  and also no need to add this $request['id'] = 1;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was in route:
Bad one:

```
Route::put('/admin/company/{id}', 'Admin\CompanyController@update')->name('admin_company_update');
```

Good one:

```
Route::put('/admin/company/{company}', 'Admin\CompanyController@update')->name('admin_company_update');
```

Just changed id with company

THX  Md Juyel Rana for helping me to solve this problem

Comment: my pleasure Young L